# Is there support for SSDT replication environment?

Tags: sql-server, deployment, replication, sql-server-data-tools

I could not locate specific, up-to-date documentation on this issue. Does publishing support already exist using SSDT in an environment with replication enabled?

If it exists, can you give me a link to a documentation?

Comment: Good day to you also! Please try to refrain from using male-oriented pronouns here - your audience is not exclusively male, and some may find that assumption exclusionary. Thank you! (We tend to edit out salutations anyway).

Comment: Hi @halfer. Thank you for edit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSDT does not support replication nor jobs.
You need to write scripts that will stop replication (or do whatever you need) before you publish and start after publishing. This can be done as pre/post deployment scripts or other scripts that are run from powershell/batch when deployment is automated.